# Should tag [mantissa] "an application server built on Twisted and Axiom" be deleted?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

*mantissa* generally means *"the non-integer part in a floating-point number representation"*

However someone [created](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12098566/revisions) a [mantissa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mantissa) with the wiki *Mantissa is an application server built on Twisted and Axiom.*

Back in 2012. Seems to have gone unnoticed till now.

Should that tag be deleted?

Comment: A quick look at the tagged questions implies that the tag is only used in the mathematical sense and never for the application server. Maybe a rewrite of the wiki would be enough?

Comment: @BillTür: I don't think a tag is needed. Simply the word 'mantissa' by itself works fine. And if people need 'mantissa server'/twisted/axiom they can write that.

Comment: I agree that the tag is not really that useful. OTOH getting rid of it would mean that all questions would have to be edited

Comment: @BillTür not necessarily. If the analysis is that none of the posts need to be cleaned up a CM can press the nuke tag button, removing the tag from all questions without a bump.

Comment: @rene Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The mantissa is the fractional part, the one that actually holds the number. The other parts are the sign and the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

As of writing, the tag has 3 watchers and 47 questions, all of which are about floating-point numbers rather than the application server. Therefore I've edited the tag usage guidance to be consistent with that:

> The mantissa of a floating-point number is the value m in the representation m × 2ᵉ, where e is the exponent. Use this tag for questions specifically about the mantissa of a floating-point number. For questions about floating-point numbers, use the [floating-point] tag instead. Do not use this tag for questions relating to the Divmod Mantissa application server.

I don't have an opinion on whether the tag is useful. If the community decides that it isn't, I suggest it should be merged with the [floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) tag rather than deleted, since a lot of the questions tagged [mantissa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mantissa) are not also tagged [floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point).

Comment: The mantissa is not always non-integer, so that sounds a bit misleading to me.

Comment: you're right, my terminology was sloppy.

Comment: I was going to do this but it looks like you beat me to it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that it's not always \$2^{e}\$. In a decimal float it can be \$10^{e}\$ and in other representations it's \$16^{e}\$.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Good point, though I'm not sure how to account for that without making the explanation longer, when the usage guidance is more important for the excerpt. Maybe it can be mentioned in the tag wiki?

Comment: That works for me.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: true but when people say 'floating-point' they invariably mean base-two, and specifically IEEE-754 standard. I've never seen hardware implementations (for floating-point) other than radix-two. (There is residue-arithmetic (RNS) for integers, but that's different)

Comment: @smci IEEE-754 specifies decimal floating-point formats too.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: okay, but I spent two years reading the literature on hardware implementations, and I never saw a hardware implementations (for floating-point) other than radix-two

Comment: @smci The tag [tag:floating-point] does not have to be mandated by the existing hardware implementations.

Comment: @smci Also take a look at [IBM hexadecimal floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_hexadecimal_floating_point).

Answer (score -1):

After a quick review, it seems that this tag is mainly used for operations with floating-point numbers. I suggest changing the tag wiki and excerpt.

Comment: I don't see that a tag is needed though, it's unambiguous, just the term alone says what it is. Don't have time to check what the tag guidelines say.